# Slowing an object in 3D space using vectors

Tags: opengl, math, linear-algebra

I am programming a fairly simple 3D minigolf game using OpenGl. I've run across a problem of slowing a minigolf ball that is rolling on a surface. The ball is described by velocity and position vectors.

When it moves on a flat surface, it must be slowed, but only in **XZ** plane (Y axis points up). The **Y** component must not be slowed, as only the ground applies friction - that of air versus ball is negligible, thus when the ball bounces, **Y** component comes into play. In order to change it, I add a gravity vector.

I'm looking for a way of decreasing speed proportionally in two axes. I tried decreasing exponentially/linearly both **X** and **Z** components, but that results in a false behavior - when moving along only one of these axes, ball slows at a lower rate than when moving in direction, say, 45 degrees, wherein both axes contribute to the velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the magnitude of the 2D velocity vector in the XZ plane as a scalar quantity, then apply your friction function to that and then convert back to a 2D vector.

In C-like pseudo code:

```
// the current velocity in each direction
float velocityX, velocityY, velocityZ;

// compute magnitude using Pythagorean Theorem:
float magnitude = sqrt((velocityX * velocityX) + (velocityZ * velocityZ));

if(magnitude > 0.0)  // is it moving?
{
    // apply friction to magnitude using whatever function you want
    //           e.g. newMagnitude = magnitude * 0.95f;
    float newMagnitude = applyFriction(magnitude);
    float scaleFactor = newMagnitude / magnitude;

    // compute the new velocity in each direction:
    velocityX *= scaleFactor;
    velocityZ *= scaleFactor;
}
```